# Microsoft account cannot connect to XBOX games on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, xbox360

We have an Asus Vivo-tab with accounts for three people (A, B, C).  They all are configured with separate Microsoft Account IDs.  Everyone can log in successfully to the tablet.

The trouble occurs when Account C logs in and opens TapTiles or Microsoft Mahjong.   These are XBOX  games and they attempt to make a connection  to the xbox server and are not successful.  If we tap on the connecting message, it shows the error message: ” *a connection to xbox  could not be established. Please check your internet connection and try again.* ”

- Account A and B can play the same games and connect to XBOX services
- Account C connects to the network/internet using same settings as the other accounts.
- Account C can use the browser and view webpages
- Account C can login to the XBOX live site on the tablet (using same Microsoft Account credentials
- Account C can open the Games hub.  After a few seconds, the logged in  status shows in upper right, then using the settings charm, we can open  the “My Setting” item and view the account information. The account details match the desired account.
- I’ve uninstalled/reinstalled the offending games with no change of outcome
- All the other services for Account C Microsoft account work correctly, email, contacts.
- Tablet OS: Windows 8 Pro, Release
- Tablet OS: Fully patched and updated as of this week.

So saying it another way.  Account C can connect to the XBOX services in multiples places on the tablet but not in the games themselves.
My question,  why is this one account blocked from, connecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using the Manage Accounts feature and removing account C.  I indicated to not save the user files for the account.  Once the account was gone (about 5 minutes )  I used Managed Accounts to re-add an account with the same Microsoft Account ID as the removed account.   Once we were logged back in to the account, we simply reinstalled the applications from the store.